# Contact us mail error

Tags: php, contact-form

My html coding for the contact form html page and below that is the php code

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="contact.php" id="contactform">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" ONFOCUS="clearDefault(this)" value="Name" size="90" style="background: #DAEDFF; border:1px solid #DAEDFF; border-radius:3px; height: 25px;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" value="Email" ONFOCUS="clearDefault(this)" id="customer_mail" size="90" style="background: #DAEDFF; border:1px solid #DAEDFF; border-radius:3px; height: 25px;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" value="Subject" ONFOCUS="clearDefault(this)" id="subject" size="90" style="background: #DAEDFF; border:1px solid #DAEDFF; border-radius:3px; height: 25px;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><textarea name="detail" cols="90" rows="8" id="detail" style="background: #DAEDFF; border:1px solid #DAEDFF; border-radius:3px;"></textarea></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 530px;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" style="background: #1B99E8; border: 1px solid #1B99E8; color: #ffffff; border-radius:3px;"></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

contact.php file

```
<?php

$subject        =   $_POST['subject'];
$detail         =   $_POST['detail'];
$customer_mail  =   $_POST['customer_mail'];
$name           =   $_POST['name'];

// Contact subject
$subject ="$subject"; 

// Details
$message="$detail";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

// From 
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='it@reverseinformatics.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo '<script language="javascript">confirm("We have received your request, our team will contact you shortly.")</script>';
echo '<script language="javascript">window.location = "contact.html"</script>';
}
else {
echo '<script language="javascript">confirm("Oops Sorry for the inconvinience.")</script>';
echo '<script language="javascript">window.location = "contact.html"</script>';
}
?>
```

Above is my code plz help me to overcome my problem since i have hosted in the site, it works well in my local server but not working in the website

Comment: we can't read your mind, post your code.

Comment: no one can help with out seeing the code that generates the error

Comment: Make sure sendmail is working on your host.

Comment: No, actually it is not connecting to my php file itself when clicking send button.

Answer (score 0):

I guess thee is problem with your code at **window.location = "contact.html"** part.
If you want to redirect to this page, try giving **absolute path**.
You may also try **window.location.href** or **window.open**.
Note that **window.open will open it in new window.**

Comment: If it is not connecting to your php file while clicking 'Send', them pls make sure that contact.php is actually there in the same folder.

Comment: s i kept dat contact.php file in the folder but then also no use same problem occurs 'The system cannot find the path specified.'

Comment: it will redirect to contact.php page when clicking send but it displays as The system cannot find the path specified.'

Comment: Weird... i hope there is no spelling mistake in filename...R u using HTML4 or HTML5? Try giving absolute path like 'http://www.example.com/example.php' in form action

Comment: is der any way doing it in java mail only jsp and java file in the folder which is running in the hosting server

Answer (score 0):

You also have a very common error a lot of people have with "Contact Us" forms.

```
// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail";
```

This will break SPF and also cause DMARC to fail and you will never get the message from some people, if your mail server you use has DMARC enabled on it.

Since DMARC is a more recent protocol, a lot of the old cookie cutter code for contact us forms - doesn't take this into account.

You can read more about that here: ["DMARC - Contact Form Nightmare"](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarccontactus/)

The suggested workaround will be to do:

```
$mail_from='it@reverseinformatics.com';
$subject ="$subject" .  $_POST['customer_mail'];
```

This way - you avoid the issue outline in the article. You won't quickly be able to hit the "Reply" button, but at least you'll get the emails from those customers who have DMARC enabled.